# Exporting 4000+ members details to pdf not rendering the data in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5, export-to-pdf

I am using an export function in my controller inorder to export the details of 4000+ members in doc and pdf format. At first the error shown as memory exhausted. So I wrote ini_set('memory_limit', '-1'); at the beginning of my function. Now the document works fine, but still export to pdf not working. The below is my function I wrote in laravel 5.2 controller.

```
protected function export() {
    ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');

    $members = MembersModel::select();
    $sortBy = Request::get('sort');
    switch ($sortBy) {
        case 'name':
            $members->orderBy('name');
            break;
        case 'member_num':
            $members->orderBy('member_num');
            break;
        case 'address':
            $members->orderBy('address');
            break;
        case 'road':
            $members->orderBy('road');
            break;
        case 'pincode':
            $members->orderBy('pincode');
            break;
        case 'city':
            $members->orderBy('city');
            break;

        default:
            # code...
            break;
    }
    $filter = Request::get('filter');
    if($filter != '') {
        $members->where('name', 'like', '%' . $filter . '%')->orWhere('member_num', 'like', '%' . $filter . '%')->orWhere('address', 'like', '%' . $filter . '%')->orWhere('address2', 'like', '%' . $filter . '%')->orWhere('road', 'like', '%' . $filter . '%')->orWhere('city', 'like', '%' . $filter . '%')->orWhere('pincode', 'like', '%' . $filter . '%')->orWhere('blood_group', 'like', '%' . $filter . '%')->orWhere('land_num', 'like', '%' . $filter . '%')->orWhere('mob_num', 'like', '%' . $filter . '%')->orWhere('occupation', 'like', '%' . $filter . '%');
    }
    $members = $members->get();

    $data = array('members' => $members);

    $type =  Request::get('type');
    switch ($type) {
        case 'doc':

            $view = View::make('allmembers.exportdoc', $data);

            $contents = $view->render();
            // or
            $contents = (string) $view;

            header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=allmembers.doc");
            echo $contents;


            break;
        case 'pdf':

            $pdf = PDF::loadView('allmembers.exportdoc', $data);
            return $pdf->download('allmembers.pdf');
            break;

        default:
            # code...
            break;
    }
}
```

What might be the issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? nothing happen? exported a blank pdf? :)

Comment: Means no pdf is generated. Shows 500 server error

Comment: Check your log file, should have more info there, /storage/logs/laravel.log by default

Comment: In logs i could only found the below error
[2016-09-01 04:21:46] local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded'.

Comment: What is your setup? Are you on localhost - i've experienced huge execution times on a WAMP server for example while XAMPP executed in like seconds. Try to increase the execution time to like 1000 seconds and try again

Comment: Even setting of max execution time is not working :(

Comment: Try to provide more details. A full error stack + the package you are using for PDF generation might be useful